# event.state of history object in html 5 is null

Tags: javascript, html, history

I'm playing with the history object for the first time.  I have the following code which I've been testing in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  console.log('popstate fired!');
   console.log(event.state);

});

function showbox()
{
   document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
   history.pushState({somethinggoeshere:'but what?'}, 'I put text here, but how do i verify the browser has received it?', '?showbox=true');
}
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <a onclick="showbox();">Show box</a>
                <div id="box" style="background:red; height:100px; display:none;"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

When i click on the link Show box, a red box appears.  When I click on the back button in the chrome browser window, then look at console.log, event.state is null.  Why is it null?  Didn't I populate this with something with history.pushState?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `pushState`, you are pushing the "*current* state" of the page (the browser doesn't actually save the state of the page.  It just associates the object passed as the 1st parameter to `pushState` with the page in history) onto the browser's history stack.  When you browse to that page in the history stack, the object you pushed will appear (in `onpopstate`).

(Note: you can pass anything that can be `JSON.stringify`ed to `pushState`.)

You went back to a page in the history, but that page wasn't added with `pushState`, so it has no "state".

Try to push the "forward" button in your browser after clicking "back".  You will see that `event.state` is not `null` then.

So, the object you pass is linked to the page that was pushed into the history stack, and you'll only see it when you visit that page in the history.

Comment: when you say "pushing the current state of the page", does "current state" include the state of #box being display=block ?  Does the browser remember to retain visibility of the box if browsed to again from history?

Comment: @John: Sorry if that was confusing.  It's just like browsing normally through the history.  The browser will only return you the object passed as the 1st parameter to `pushState`.  It won't remember anything about the page, except the URL.  That's up to you.

Comment: Thanks fo rthe answer.  I followed up with another basic question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633691/html-5-history-remembers-restores-some-changes-and-not-others

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea for thinking.

I have got the same problem working with [Dart](https://dart.dev/) programming language.`PopStateEvent` listener provide `null` in the event state parameter.
I have solved this issue by using `HashChangeEvent` listener.
After press "Back" button in the browser the `HashChangeEvent` listener is fire, providing useful information.

```
window.onHashChange.listen((event) {
    var e = event as HashChangeEvent;
    var newUrl = e.newUrl;
    var oldUrl = e.oldUrl;
      // please, navigate to the "state" (old history location)

  });
```