# html 5 history restores some changes and not others?

Tags: javascript, html, history

I'm new to using the html 5 history object.  I tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">

   history.pushState({somethinggoeshere:'but what?'}, 'Does a title go here?', '?begin=true');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  console.log('popstate fired!');
   console.log(event.state);

});

function dosomething()
{
   document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('iframe').src = 't2.html';
   history.pushState({somethinggoeshere:'but what?'}, 'Does a title go here?', '?complete=true');
}

                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <a onclick="dosomething();">Show box</a>
                <div id="box" style="background:red; height:100px; display:none;"></div>
               <iframe id="iframe" src="t1.html"></iframe>
        </body>
</html>
```

When I press Show box, a red box appears below, and the contents of the iframe goes from t1.html to t2.html.  When I press the back button in the chrome browser, the contents of the iframe goes back to t1.html , but the red box does not disappear.

**Why does the back button restore the content of the iframe** but not the css styles of the redbox (back to display:none);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser's history is just a list of URLs.  `pushState` lets you associate an object with a URL in the history, a "state" if you will.  This object is the 1st parameter passed to `pushState`.

Just like when browsing the history "normally", the *actual* state of the page isn't saved.  That's up to you.  In your object, you should save that the red box should be shown, and in `onpopstate` show it again.

Such as:

```
history.pushState({
    redBox: document.getElementById('box').style.display
}, 'Most browsers ignore this parameter.', '?complete=true');
```

Then in `onpopstate`, set `document.getElementById('box').style.display` to `event.state.redBox`.

**EDIT**: The iFrame is like a new browser window, so it has its own history object.  When you click "back", the iFrame sees that and goes back in history.  You need to have `window.addEventListener('popstate', function()` inside the page in the iFrame too.

Comment: Thanks Rocket, I bolded the question in my question description above.  I guess that's the real question i'm confused about.

Comment: The back and forward buttons just change the history.  The history is just a list of URLs.  It doesn't contain any info about the page.  You need to re-show the red box yourself.  The history just re-loads the URL.

Comment: Yeah, but how come the back button causes iframe.src to change from t2.html to t1.html?  I was expecting to do that mysqlf programmatically  in the onpopstate?

Comment: I think it's because the iFrame is its own page, so it's reading the back button and changing the page.  I think you need to add an `onpopstate` event to the page inside the iFrame too.

Comment: in my real code, iframe.src is actually a link to a youtube video or vimeo video.  I guess I can't put an onpopstate for those things?  It's a littl confusing to me what changes needs ot be programmatically done, and what doesn't on the onpopstate.  thanks f

Comment: `popState` is kinda weird.  I've never used it on page with an iFrame, so I'm not sure how it works.  I'm just kinda guessing.  That's what I think is going on.